# Нужно распределить нагрузку между серверами Nginx,для более быстрой загрузки магазина

Tags: node.js, nginx, веб-сервер

У меня есть интернет магазин на стеке MERN ,который работает в разных странах. Все работает на VPS сервере, который находится в Европе.
Проблема заключается в том,что для пользователей из Европы все ок ,а у пользователей из США ,сайт загружается долго.

Я предполагаю ,что проблема в расстоянии до сервера и хочу купить еще 1 в США.

Вопрос заключается в том, как это все правильно реализовать.

В качестве веб-сервера я использую nginx.Я слышал что-то об Load Balancer,но так и не понял, ускорит ли это загрузку фронта или только быстрее дата с сервера будет фетчитсья.

В общем если кто-то с таким сталкивался или есть идеи,как мне это лучше реализовать ,буду рад!

Answer (score 1):

Я считаю что распределение не поможет, тк в любом случае часть функционала с серверов в Европе будет тормозить скорость. Попробуй просто докупить скорость у хоста